# Evaluate: $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)!!^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to evaluate this sum?
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{i}\frac{j(j-1/2)}{(j+1/2)^2}$$

$$\frac{j(j-1/2)}{(j+1/2)^2}=\frac{2j(2j-1)}{(2j+1)^2}$$

$$S=\prod_{j=1}^{1}\frac{2j(2j-1)}{(2j+1)^2}+\prod_{j=1}^{2}\frac{2j(2j-1)}{(2j+1)^2}+\prod_{j=1}^{3}\frac{2j(2j-1)}{(2j+1)^2}+\cdots$$

$$S=\frac{1\cdot2}{3^2}+\frac{1\cdot2}{3^2}\cdot\frac{3\cdot4}{5^2}+\frac{1\cdot2}{3^2}\cdot\frac{3\cdot4}{5^2}\cdot\frac{5\cdot6}{7^2}+\cdots+\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)!!^2}$$

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)!!^2}$$

Comment: Dr. Qamber, if you're interested in a reference, see *Ramanujan's Notebook Part I by Bruce C. Berdt (chapter 9, entry 32, example i)* for this and similar identities and generalisations.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that there are several ways to arrive to the result.

I am not very happy with the following
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{\big[(2n+1)!!\big]^2}x^{n-1}=\frac{2}{9} \, _3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};x\right)$$

$$S(1)=2 C-1$$ where $C$ is Catalan constant.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing one of the integral representations of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant), $$2G=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\cot\frac{x}{2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\cos^{2n+1}x}{2n+1}\,dx\\=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2n+1}\mathrm{B}\left(n+1,\frac12\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!!(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)!!^2}.$$